# why dosn't this onchange work

Tags: javascript, select, tags, onchange

I am trying to work out a simple problem in js. I can't figure out why my speed method is not being called. I've inserted console.log() to check if every other method works and turns out it does. I've inserted code from html and js. It is a selection list, if i select a different value, speed method should be called, but it never does. Any help is appreciated.

```
(function() {
"use strict";
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("startbutton").onclick = displayWords;
    document.getElementById("stopbutton").onclick =  stop;  
    document.getElementById("speedMenu").onchange = speed;
};

var timer = null;
var speed = 171;
var count = 0;


function displayWords() {
    console.log(" displayWords is called");
    document.getElementById("stopbutton").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("startbutton").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("stopbutton").classList.remove("buttonBehaviour");
    document.getElementById("startbutton").classList.add("buttonBehaviour");
    document.getElementById("input").disabled = true;
    timer = setInterval(display,speed,punctuation());
}
function stop() {
    console.log(" stop is called");
    document.getElementById("startbutton").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("stopbutton").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("stopbutton").classList.add("buttonBehaviour");
    document.getElementById("startbutton").classList.remove("buttonBehaviour");
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "";
    clearInterval(timer);
    document.getElementById("input").disabled = false;
    count = 0;
}

function speed() {
    console.log(" speed is called");
    var value = document.getElementById("speedMenu").options[document.getElementById("speedMenu")].value;
    console.log(value);
    clearInterval(timer);
    var list = punctuation();
    for(var i = 0; i < count ;i++) {
        list.shift();
    }
    timer = setInterval(display,value,list);
}

function punctuation () {
    console.log(" pun is called");
    var words = document.getElementById("input").value.split(/[ \t\n]+/);
    var list = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        var word = words[i];
        var lastChar = word.charAt(word.length - 1);
        if(lastChar === "," || lastChar === "." || lastChar === "!" || lastChar === "?" || lastChar === ";" || lastChar === ":") {
            word = word.substring(0,word.length - 1);
            list.push(word);
            list.push(word);
        } else {
            list.push(word);
        }
    };
    return list;
}
function display(words) {
    count++;
    console.log(" display  is called");
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = words.shift();
        if(document.getElementById("med").checked) {
            document.getElementById("display").style.fontSize = "36pt";
        } else if(document.getElementById("big").checked) {
            document.getElementById("display").style.fontSize = "48pt";
        } else if(document.getElementById("bigger").checked) {
            document.getElementById("display").style.fontSize = "60pt";
        }
        if( words.length == 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
}
}) ();
```

HTML code is following for the tag and method

```
<select id = "speedMenu">
                <option value = "500">50 wpm</option>
                <option value = "200">300 wpm</option>
                <option value = "171" selected="selected">350 wpm</option>
                <option value = "150">400 wpm</option>
                <option value = "133">450 wpm</option>
                <option value = "120">500 wpm</option>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a variable named speed and a function named speed. You have a name collision.

This is the minimal example of your code:

```js
window.onload = function () {
    console.log(speed);  
};
var speed = 171;

function speed(){

}
```

Comment: OMG i feel so stupid but thanks a lot for the catch!!